# Adding calculated columns to the Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, calculated-columns

There is a large csv file imported. Below is the output, where `Flavor_Score` and `Overall_Score` are results of applying `df.groupby('beer_name').mean()` across a multitude of testers. I would like to add a column Std Deviation for each: `Flavor_Score` and `Overall_Score` to the right of the mean column. The function is clear but how to add a column for display? Of course, I can generate an array and append it (right?) but it would seem to be a cumbersome way.

```
  Beer_name        Beer_Style     Flavor_Score         Overall_Score

  Coors               Light          2.0                    3.0
  Sam Adams           Dark           4.0                    4.5
  Becks               Light          3.5                    3.5
  Guinness            Dark           2.0                    2.2
  Heineken            Light          3.5                    3.7
```

Comment: Is this a question of how do you add columns to a dataframe?

Comment: You could do something like yourDataFrame['Flavor_Score_stddev'] = yourDataFrame['Flavor_Score'].someFunction() to map values of  'Flavor_Score' to new values using someFunction() and put the new values in a new column named 'Flavor_Score_stddev'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
df.groupby('Beer_name').agg(['mean','std'])
```

This computes the mean and the std for each group.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 100
beers = ['Coors', 'Sam Adams', 'Becks', 'Guinness', 'Heineken']
style = ['Light', 'Dark', 'Light', 'Dark', 'Light']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Beer_name': np.random.choice(beers, N),
                   'Flavor_Score': np.random.uniform(0, 10, N),
                   'Overall_Score': np.random.uniform(0, 10, N)})
df['Beer_Style'] = df['Beer_name'].map(dict(zip(beers, style)))

print(df.groupby('Beer_name').agg(['mean','std']))
```

yields

```
          Flavor_Score           Overall_Score          
                  mean       std          mean       std
Beer_name                                               
Becks         5.779266  3.033939      6.995177  2.697787
Coors         6.521966  2.008911      4.066374  3.070217
Guinness      4.836690  2.644291      5.577085  2.466997
Heineken      4.622213  3.108812      6.372361  2.904932
Sam Adams     5.443279  3.311825      4.697961  3.164757
```

Comment: it works. Thanks! One caveat: this method calculates mean and std for all columns in my dataframe. How can particular columns can be selected?

Comment: @Toly `df.groupby('Beer_name')['Flavor_Score', 'Overall_Score'].agg(['mean','std'])`

Comment: @Alexander - should not I sort the column before the use of df.groupby ?

Answer (score 0):

[`groupby.agg([fun1, fun2])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) computes any number of functions in one step:

```
from random import choice, random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

beers = ['Coors', 'Sam Adams', 'Becks', 'Guinness', 'Heineken']
styles = ['Light', 'Dark']

def generate():
    for i in xrange(0, 100):
        yield dict(beer=choice(beers), style=choice(styles), 
                   flavor_score=random()*10.0,  
                   overall_score=random()*10.0)

pd.options.display.float_format = ' {:,.1f}  '.format
df = pd.DataFrame(generate())
print df.groupby(['beer', 'style']).agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

=>

```
               flavor_score        overall_score       
                        mean    std          mean    std
beer      style                                         
Becks     Dark         7.1    3.6           1.9    1.6  
          Light        4.7    2.4           2.0    1.0  
Coors     Dark         5.5    3.2           2.6    1.1  
          Light        5.3    2.5           1.9    1.1  
Guinness  Dark         3.3    1.4           2.1    1.1  
          Light        4.7    3.6           2.2    1.1  
Heineken  Dark         4.4    3.0           2.7    1.0  
          Light        6.0    2.3           2.1    1.3  
Sam Adams Dark         3.4    3.0           1.7    1.2  
          Light        5.2    3.6           1.6    1.3
```

> What if I need to use a user-defined function to just a flavor_score column? let's say I want subtract 0.5 from a flavor_score column (from all rows, except for Heineken, for which I want to add 0.25)

```
grouped[grouped.beer != 'Heineken']['flavor_score']['mean'] - 0.5
grouped[grouped.beer == 'Heineken']['flavor_score']['mean'] + 0.25
```

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you! This helps! One more question: what if I need to use a user-defined function to just a flavor_score column? let's say I want subtract 0.5 from a flavor_score column (from all rows, except for Heineken, for which I want to add 0.25). I tried to use df.loc operator but for some reason the value in the column did not change